# Debatching Biztalk Flatfile Schema with nested repeating nodes

Tags: xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a flatfile with nested repeating nodes that needs needs to be debatched to single records.

The flatfile:

```
ABC DEF  1234.456789012345678
000000123456L01   Supplier 0
001000123456L01   00301Address 1                                 
000001234567L01   Supplier 1
001001234567L01   00301Address 2
001001234567L01   00301Address 3
001001234567L01   00302Address 4
```

Lines starting with 000 are Suppliers, starting with 001 are Supplier addresses.
Characters 4-15 are the supplier-code.

Currently I cannot get beyond outputting one record with all addresses per supplier:

```
<Record>
  <Supplier>
    <Supplier_code>001234567L01</Supplier_code>
    <Supplier_name>Supplier 1</Supplier_name>
  </Supplier>
  <Address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_2</Supplier_address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_3</Supplier_address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_4</Supplier_address>
  </Address>
</Record>
```

However, the expected output is one record per supplier address:

```
<Record>
  <Supplier>
    <Supplier_code>001234567L01</Supplier_code>
    <Supplier_name>Supplier 1</Supplier_name>
  </Supplier>
  <Address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_2</Supplier_address>
  </Address>
</Record>

<Record>
  <Supplier>
    <Supplier_code>001234567L01</Supplier_code>
    <Supplier_name>Supplier 1</Supplier_name>
  </Supplier>
  <Address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_3</Supplier_address>
  </Address>
</Record>


<Record>
  <Supplier>
    <Supplier_code>001234567L01</Supplier_code>
    <Supplier_name>Supplier 1</Supplier_name>
  </Supplier>
  <Address>
    <Supplier_address>Address_4</Supplier_address>
  </Address>
</Record>
```

How would I need to alter my FlatFile schema to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in one pass with the flat file disassembler.  There's no way to indicate to it that certain nodes need to be grouped/split/etc.   It'd be fairly trivial to do this in a map though.  Create a new Schema that's structured like your first, but has an additional root node to allow the `Record`s to repeat, and your map will look like this:

[image: looping split map sample]

And just make sure `MaxOccurs` is set properly (probably `unbounded`) on the `Supplier_address` element and the destination `Record` node.  Add this map to your receive port and it'll come into the MessageBox split up as desired.  Note that you do need a new schema, because you can't have a message with multiple root nodes.  If you need to further debatch that, you could set it up as an envelope schema, have a request response port subscribe to it, and use the XML disassembler on the response end to debatch it.  Your only other option would be to do this in a custom pipeline component after the flat file dasm has done its magic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already suspected this was no-go. A custom pipeline component is a bit too much though, I'd like to keep things out-of-the-box. So, a map it is. Following the sample you provided I got it working.